# Infeasible paths in path coverage

Tags: testing, graph, linear-programming

in the image in the link

[image]

is it **correct** to say the Infeasible path is

```
If score < 45 
/*C*/ then print (‘fail’)
/*D*/ else print (`pass’);
```

this is infeasible because if score is greater than 80 it would have determined the message pass even though the next if statement will be executed.

In the graph the infeasible graph is represented `as <b,d,e>` am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*is it correct to say the Infeasible path is*

```
If score < 45 
/*C*/ then print (‘fail’)
/*D*/ else print (`pass’);
```

The Answer is **No.**, Because **either** of the path would be **`Traversed`**.

**`Explanation`**

If the score is grater than **`80`**: It would print **`Pass with Distinction`** which is perfect.

If score is **60** then it will print **`Pass`**

If score is **40** then it will print **`Fail`**

Hence all the paths are **`Feasible`**.

Answer (score 1):

In the graph all the paths will be traversed with atleast one test case.. with score greater than 80 it might determinte that it is a pass but providing information that score is 'distinction' or not is a complete new information. I don't think that can be considered as candidate for infeasible graph.